# advertising servers / advert delivery solutions for C#/Asp.Net

Tags: advertising, google-dfp, ad-server

We have a website which we want to show adverts in - However, these are custom adverts uploaded by the webmaster, not the Google adverts, or any adverts the network chooses.  Ideally, there would be both options.  We were considering developing our own advert-management system, but looking at the big picture, it might be better to consider other alternatives.  Website is currently developed in C# / ASP.Net (Web Forms)

Are there any recommendations to some open-source delivery networks and/or external hosted advert delivery networks?

Personally I've used Google's DFP, however sometimes it is not so easy to get a Google AdSense account approved, especially while developing a new website and it not yet being launched.

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this kind of question!

Comment: Have a look at adzerk.com's hosted solution. I heard a lot of good things about it, and it features a developer friendly API.

Answer (score 1):

Check out www.adzerk.com/ it will give you your own dashboard to upload and manage the ads from, its free for up to 100m impressions per month.

To install it all you have to do is ad a piece of js in the head of the page you want the ad on, and then place the ad  where you want the ad to be displayed.

Its what the stack exchange network uses to run on, and can also be expanded to allow advertisers their own login and dashoboard to upload and manage their campaigns.

Comment: I'm looking into this, and it looks very good!  Will give it an actual try and let you know :)